# Recordset is not updateable when using group by in query with checkbox

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

The checkbox on my continuous form cannot be checked, the recordset is not updateable, because I'm using group by (sum). The reason for this: It is summing up the value of a column (to show a total) if they have the same ID. So the checkbox can't be marked because it's not a single record.

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW WorkTable.ItemCode, Sum(WorkTable.QuantityInventory) AS SumOfQuantityInventory, 
WorkTable.ItemName, WorkTable.CheckBox
FROM WorkTable
GROUP BY WorkTable.ItemCode, WorkTable.ItemName, WorkTable.CheckBox
HAVING (((Sum(WorkTable.QuantityInventory)) Is Not Null) AND ((WorkTable.CheckBox)=False));
```

Can I make the checkbox clickable by adjusting my query, or my second idea, to have the checkbox event: On Click, and make a VBA that checks all checkbox if they have the same ID, but I have no clue where to begin on this.

The reason for this is, when the checkbox is marked, the record won't show up next time in the continuous form, or are there any better ways to do it?

I have looked at many other examples and have managed to bypass this by adding a subform in the main form, which is also a continuous form. In that subform it shows all records just like the main one, but the difference is, they are not sorted by sum and they are not grouped, so you can see records with the same ID several times and have to mark each checkbox in order to have that entire ID marked. But this takes a while and is a hassle as compared to a single checkbox that marks all of the records with the same ID.

Comment: @braX That would be the ItemCode, in the continuous form all the records are aligned, so when I mark the checkbox it might be able to mark all the checkboces with the same ItemCode

Comment: @braX the problem is that I can't mark the checkbox because recordset is not updateable it says

Comment: it sounds like you want to update multiple records in a subform based on the group that is selected in the main form? What if you make the checkbox column unbound and then use a VBA event to update those records based on the group id?

Comment: @braX from the main continuous form I would like to try that but I don't know where to begin, to make a VBA in the checkbox that when I click it, that it then marks all records with the corresponding id

Comment: If checkbox Click event is not available because query is not updateable (did you try?), can use a command button instead (I tested and this works). Code would run an UPDATE action SQL. Not difficult at all. Do you know how to develop VBA procedures?

Comment: If you group records, the data shown in the SQL result are not records in the database and therefore can't be updated.

Comment: @FunThomas, true, but can UPDATE records query is based on by using value from query as criteria - that's what OP is really looking for. I confirmed that textbox Click event is available even though data cannot be edited, did not try checkbox.

Comment: @june7 I only know a little bit about VBA procedures I will try this tomorrow.